# vue.js is not updating the DOM after updating the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I read a list of items via AJAX and push it into a data Array:

```
loadSparepartFiles: function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.activeSparepart.attachments = [];
    ajaxApi.loadJson('spareparts/sparepart/getFiles/'+vm.activeSparepartId, function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
            vm.activeSparepart.attachments.push({
                filename: data.files[i]
            });
        }
    });
},
```

In the Vue devTools in Chrome I can see the updated data array, but the DOM list is still empty.

The template:

```
<div v-for="file in activeSparepart.attachments" class="uk-width-1-2 uk-margin-bottom">
    <a href="{{ baseUrl }}/download/sparepart/{{ activeSparepartId }}/{{ file.filename }}" target="hidden-frame" class="block-link">
        <i class="delete uk-icon-remove"></i>
        <i class="icon uk-icon-image"></i>
        <span class="title">
            {{ file.filename }}
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The `activeSparepart` Object is initialised here:

```
resetSparepart: function() {
    this.activeSparepart = {
        alternates: [],
        locations: [],
        logs: [],
        usages: [],
        vendors: [],
        sparepart: {},
        attachments: []
    };
    this.activeSparepartId = 'new';
},
```

Vue devTools shows the following:

[image]

Comment: Provide jsFiddle because it's impossible to know what you are doing in the template

Comment: I added the template to the question.

Comment: how is your `activeSparepart` defined in the component?

Comment: i call the resetSparepart method on vue ready

Comment: the point i don't understand ist, that the vue devtools show the correct content in activeSparepart.attachments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `activeSparepart.attachments` is not reactive.

Read about [Change Detection Caveats in Vue: For Arrays](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/change-detection.html#for-arrays) for the short answer, or learn about [Vue Reactivity in Depth](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#what-is-reactivity).

If `activeSparepart` is an object and you add property `attachments` the attachments will not be recognised...

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method:

```
Vue.set(vm.activeSparepart, 'attachments', [])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! +1

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you define Vue.js component data as a function
returning a whole new object to prevent the data been shared with other components. If you wish to modify an array, you need to first get the whole thing, make changes, and put the whole thing back again.

```
var list = vm.activeSparepart.attachments;
for (var i=0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
    list.push({ filename: data.files[i] });
}
vm.activeSparepart.attachments = list;
```

Comment: `array.push()` will detect changes and offer reactivity

Comment: still the same result :(

Comment: gee... sorry my bad