# how to v-model for array of objects

Tags: vue.js

I have and array of objects, this is indefinite array, may push or splice things here. I need to bind the property of an object to a input dom with vue, doesnt seem to work.

## heres the data

```
   items : [
     { prop1: 123, prop2: 'test', prop3: 'foo' },
     { prop1: 321, prop2: 'tset', prop3: 'bar' },
   ]

}
```

## trying to do

```
   <li v-for="item in items"> 
      {{ item.prop2 }} 
      <input type="text" v-model="item.prop1">
   </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use index to do that. For example:

```
   <li v-for="(item, index) of items"> 
      {{ item.prop2 }} 
      <input type="text" v-model="items[index].prop2">
   </li>
```

Another way to do that and I recommend it is to use a event, like `v-on:input` or simply `@input` on yout input an call a method that find your item in your `items` to change your `prop2` value.

```
   <li v-for="(item, index) of items"> 
      {{ item.prop2 }} 
      <input type="text" @input="updateMyProp(index)">
   </li>
```

```
   ...
   methods: {
     updateMyProp ($event, index) {
       // your update logic here
       // you can use 'this.items', Object.assign, Vue.set, etc... to update your value
     }
   ...
```

Comment: sometimes, updating some array item on your data does not update the DOM directly and you must enforce Vue to do that. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794632/vue-js-is-not-updating-the-dom-after-updating-the-array?rq=1

Comment: thanks, looks like Vue doesnt detect changes on object array if you add a property like `data[index].prop = value` I did `$this.set(item, 'prop', value)` and it worked

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Late comment but it might still be useful to someone that stumbles upon it: remember to set your component keys! 
`<input type="text" v-model="items[index].prop2" :key='items[index].unique_prop'>`
NOT `<input type="text" v-model="items[index].prop2" :key='item.unique_prop'>`
I experienced that the latter does not work with item slots on v-autocomplete components. Probably others too.

Comment: Shoudn't `@input="updateMyProp(index)` be `@input="updateMyProp($event, index)`?

Comment: Is this issue fixed in vue3?