# How to bind an object to HTML table in Vue.js, where its properties are dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, vue.js

I am using  vue.js library for front-end development.

I came a cross a scenario where my JavaScript method returns a list, which has objects, object's number of properties can change each time after method execution.

example my list can contain these type of objects in 2 different executions.
`var obj = {
            Name : "John",
            2020-Jan:  1,
            2020-Jul:  2
}`
`var obj = {
            Name: "John",
            2020-Jan: 1,
            2020-Jul: 2,
            2021-Jan: 3,
            2021-Jul: 4
}`

Since Property name is dynamically changes is there any way to bind to HTML ?

```
 <div >
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for ="row in Result.Headers">
                {{row}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in Result.Data ">
                 <td>
                    {{item.2020-Jan}}       // Because don't know the number of properties until run time
                </td>                   // No of <td/>'s can change on no of properties. 
                 <td>                   // exactly don't know how many <td>'s needed there.
                    {{item.2020-Jul}}
                </td> <td>
                    {{item.2021-Jan}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there way to bind these type of object to fronted in vue.js ?

Comment: is `Result` an object, array, or array of objects?

Comment: @StevenB. Result.Data is an Object array.. of similar type.Sorry ill edit the code.I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the item's keys again. This will show all the values in the object

```
<tbody>
 <tr v-for="item in Result.Data ">
  <td v-for="(value, key, index) in item">
    {{value}}
   </td>  
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If you want to filter some of them, for instance check that the keys are valid dates you need to add a `v-if` and use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to check for this.

```
<tbody>
 <tr v-for="item in Result.Data ">
  <td v-for="(value, key, index) in item" v-if="Date.parse(key) !== NaN">
    {{value}}
   </td>  
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Dita. i load data on button click. Data loaded on first button click. when i click for the second time it didn't get load. but when i change the  a drop down value the data got visible. I think data is not updating here.But data is there. it won't show until a refresh a happen, like drop down value change. thanks

Answer (score 1):

if u wana show all attr-> u can use this:

```
    <ul v-for="item in Result ">
      <li v-for="(value,key,index) in item">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
```

if u wana show all days u can use v-if and compute to complete youself fillter

```
  <div id="app">
      <ul v-for="item in Result" >
          <li v-for="(value,key,index) in item" v-if="canShow(key)"> index：{{index}}------ key: {{key}} ------ value：{{value}} </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

<script>
    var  vue=new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            Result:[{
                name: 'SkyManss',
                2020-Jan: 1,
                2020-Jul: 2
            },{
                name: 'SkyManss2',
                2020-Jan: 1,
                2020-Jul: 2,
                2021-Jan: 3,
                2021-Jul: 4
            }]
        },
        computed:{
          canShow(){
            return function(skey){
                return skey.indexOf('-') > -1;         
            }     
          }
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have edited the question. it is not a counter type

Answer (score 0):

after some research and some of your suggestions I came up with an answer.

```
 <div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for ="row in Result.Headers">
                {{row}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in  Result.Data ">
                <td v-for="row in Result.Headers">
                    {{item[row]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
this.Result.Headers =  Object.keys(result.data[0]);
this.Result.Data    =  result.data;
```

But this code only worked for the first time. second time data didn't get updated. So I updated JavaScript code to following code.

```
 Vue.set(self.Result, 'Headers', []);
 Vue.set(self.Result, 'Result', []);
 this.Result.Headers =  Object.keys(result.data[0]);
 this.Result.Data    =  result.data;
```

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. That I got to know from following post.

[vue.js is not updating the DOM after updating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794632/vue-js-is-not-updating-the-dom-after-updating-the-array)

Thank You All !!!